# Using <logic:iterate> with Struts 1.x

Tags: jsp, struts-1

I am new to Struts 1.x. I need to iterate `List<List<VO>>` in a JSP using `<logic: iterate>`

`List<List<VO>>` -- defined in Form

from that I am able to get and Outer List. Now using an id, I get the inner list. My `List<Vo>` used to fill the combo-boxes.

How do I get the properties of VO from `<logic:iterate>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's been a while since I used Struts 1.x, but IIRC you should be able to access the VO from inside a `<logic:iterate>`.

Assuming you have something like this in your Action (`PersonForm` is the VO, and it contains a list of email addresses):

```
List<EmailAddress> emailAddresses = new ArrayList<EmailAddress>();
emailAddresses.add(new EmailAddress("bob@bob.com"));
emailAddresses.add(new EmailAddress("bob@somewhere-else.com"));

PersonForm personForm = new PersonForm();
personForm.setFirstName("Robert");
personForm.setEmailAddresses(emailAddresses);

request.setAttribute("myPersonForm", personForm );
```

And then the following in your JSP:

```
<logic:iterate name="myPersonForm" property="emailAddresses" id="email">
  <li><bean:write name="myPersonForm" property="firstName" /></li>
  <li><bean:write name="email" property="address"/></li>
</logic:iterate>
```

That should print out something like:

- Robert
- bob@bob.com
- Robert
- bob@somewhere-else.com